# Splash screen not showing during boot in Ubuntu 16.04 but works fine while shut down

Tags: 16.04, boot, plymouth, macbuntu

I have installed Macbuntu 16.04 transformation pack on my Ubuntu. The splash screen (or boot screen) does not show up during boot. It just shows a black screen and then the `lightdm-webkit-greeter` comes up. But during shut down it works fine.

I tried to reconfigure it. So in terminal I typed:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

which showed:

```
There are 4 choices for the alternative default.plymouth (providing /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth).

  Selection    Path                                                                 Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------
  0            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/macbuntu/macbuntu.plymouth                 100       auto mode
* 1            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/macbuntu/macbuntu.plymouth                 100       manual mode
  2            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/spinner/spinner.plymouth                   70        manual mode
  3            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo-scale-2.plymouth   99        manual mode
  4            /usr/share/plymouth/themes/ubuntu-logo/ubuntu-logo.plymouth           100       manual mode

Press <enter> to keep the current choice[*], or type selection number: 1
```

and then the prompt appears without any error.

Then I typed :

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

which resulted in:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-37-generic
```

and then again the user prompt comes up without any error.

When I reboot, it does not show the boot screen while booting up.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the mistake..

I just changed the number from 1 to 0 during configuration and it worked for me